# Get tabs to show up along with view and model on error in mvc controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a set of jquery tabs which each contain a datatable.  When i post data on a tab, i want to check if its a duplicate.  If its a duplicate i want to load the that view back in (AddLocation.cshtml) but its just loading that view, without the tabs.

**Before save:**
[image]

**After save (notice tabs missing):**

[image]

**AddEditLocation.cshtml:**

```
@model APro.Model.DTO.DTOAddEditLocation

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Location";
}
<h2>@(Model.LocationId == Guid.Empty ? "Add Location" : "Edit Location")</h2>

<div id="AddEditLocation">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveLocation", "Management",
                                                new AjaxOptions
                                                {
                                                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                                                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                    UpdateTargetId = "AddEditLocation",
                                                },
                                                new { id = "AddEditLocationForm", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.Label("Location Name", new { @class = "control-label required-field" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LocationName, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.Label("Location Category", new { @class = "control-label required-field" })
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LocationCategoryId,
                        new SelectList(Model.LocationCategoryList, "Id", "Description"), "-- Please select a company --"
                        , new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.LocationId)

        <input type="button" id="btnReset" class="btn btn-default mr10 mb10 mt25" value="Cancel" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr10 mb10 mt25" value="Save" id="saveRole" />
    }
</div>


@if ((string)ViewBag.ErrorMessage != null)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("~/Views//Error/ErrorDuplicate.cshtml", (string)ViewBag.ErrorMessage);
    }
<div id="errorModal"></div>

<script>
    $("#AddEditLocation").on('click', '#btnReset', function (event) {
        $.get("GlobalData/Index?activeTab=5", function (data) {
            $(".body-content").replaceWith(data);
        });
    });

</script>
```

**ErrorDuplicate.cshtml:**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.modal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Model
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
  public ActionResult Index(int activeTab = 0)
        {
            ViewBag.ActiveTab = activeTab;
            return View("GlobalDataTabs");
        }

  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveLocation(DTOAddEditLocation obj)
        {
            var result = _globalDataService.SaveLocation(obj);
            if (!result)
            {
                obj.LocationCategoryList = _globalDataService.GetCategoryLocationList();
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage =
                    "The Location name " + obj.LocationName + " already exists.";      

                return View("AddEditLocation", obj);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { activeTab = 5 });
        }

        public PartialViewResult ShowError(String sErrorMessage)
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Error/ErrorDuplicate.cshtml");
        }
```

**GlobalDataTabs.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Global Data";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Global Data</h2>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#GlobalDataTabs").tabs();
        var activeTab = '@ViewBag.ActiveTab'
        $("#GlobalDataTabs").tabs("option", "active", activeTab);
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    });
</script>

<div id="GlobalDataTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#categoryTab">Category</a></li>
        <li><a href="#subCategoryTab">Subcategory</a></li>
        <li><a href="#subCategoryDescTab">Subcategory Description</a></li>
        <li><a href="#descLookupTab">Description Lookup</a></li>
        <li><a href="#locationCategoryTab">Location Category</a></li>
        <li><a href="#locationTab">Location</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="categoryTab">
        @Html.Partial("Category")
    </div>
    <div id="subCategoryTab">
        @Html.Partial("Subcategory")
    </div>
    <div id="subCategoryDescTab">
        @Html.Partial("SubcategoryDescription")
    </div>
    <div id="descLookupTab">
        @Html.Partial("DescriptionLookup")
    </div>
    <div id="locationCategoryTab">
        @Html.Partial("LocationCategory")
    </div>

    <div id="locationTab">
        @Html.Partial("Location")
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not clear what your asking.You have a `@AjaxBeginForm()` method that submits to a method that has a `return RedirectToAction()` - but ajax calls can never redirect. And the fact that it is only displaying the partial suggest that you do not have `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` loaded (or its loaded incorrectly) so its just making a normal submit

Comment: But you should be just returning a `JsonResult` if there is an error (and display the message based on that). There is no need to degrade performance by loading the same html again

Comment: @StephenMuecke i think i did take unobstrusive jquery out for the time being because of duplicated modal issues.  What im trying to achieve is, when result is false, esentially just reload the page, with the tabs still showing, with the data from the model, and showing the boostrap modal.

Comment: Why do you need to reload the page? All you need to to display the error message so you method should just return the message and you can update the DOM with it. And scripts should never be in partial views, and you should start by getting rid of `Ajax.BeginForm()` and use the `$.ajax()` methods

Comment: Ok, i can redo it as an ajax post for the submit.  How would i get the error message as a jsonresult back into the modal

Comment: `RedirectToAction` method is not intended to use with `Ajax.BeginForm` - it should use `Html.BeginForm` instead. If you want to submit form and return a partial view simply use `jQuery.ajax()` method - no need to redirect. Also your partial view contains script tags which is not a good practice - place them inside parent view instead.

Comment: Your method could `return JsonResult{ new { success = true })` if successful, or `return JsonResult( new { succss = false, errormessage = "..." });` if not, and then in the ajax callback, check the value of `data.success` and if `false`, display the error message

Comment: To get error message either you have `error` part if AJAX call failed - or use `return Json( new { success = false, message = "something" })` and fetch data from there in `success` part (`if (data.success = false) { alert(data.message) }`).

Comment: And your script for the 'reset' makes no sense either - why make an ajax call to reload all the html instead of just resetting the current form controls to their default

Comment: @StephenMuecke im not sure i understand.  btnReset is really just cancel which takes you back to the previous page (a datatable)

Comment: But why make an ajax call to do that - it can be all be done on the client.

Comment: @StephenMuecke enlighten me, i'm a sponge right now :)

Comment: `<input type="reset" value="Reset">` ([sample code](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_reset))

Comment: so it's actually loading a different page, not resetting all form controls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158819/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tshoemake).